# Adding attributes to existing object

Tags: java, oop, object, design-patterns, state

I have an existing REST application which is caching a POJO (E.g Trade object) to ehcache and many other applications are using that. Some are sending that Trade object to REST service so that it can be persisted to Cache and DB and some are doing get operation on this cache using REST service.

```
public class Trade implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -92565215465632589L;
    private String tradeNo = new String();
    private String isin = new String();
    private String quantity = new String();

.... //getters and setters 
}
```

Now I want to add one more component to our application which uses many of the above trade attributes and many new also I want to add as a part of the functionality. I don't want to add new attributes to exist Trade POJO as it will impact existing code also. Shall I create new POJO which will extend Trade and add new attributes and persist this new POJO to cache? I will have almost similar object in cache with this approach :-( . any other good approach or design pattern is available?

```
public class ExtendedTrade extends Trade {
    private String operation = new String();
    private String dealType = new String();
    private String identifier = new String();

.... //getters and setters 
}
```

Above is the `ExtendedTrade` that I was describing in my approach.

Also please suggest any design so that I can avoid caching this similar type of object.

Comment: You have a curious style of initializing Strings with `new String();`.

Comment: Make `Trade` as a member of new class if there isn't any polymorphic requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding (maybe with delegate pattern) seems more solid under circumstances.

```
public class ExtendedTrade {
    private Trade trade;
    private String operation = "";
    private String dealType = "";
    private String identifier = "";

.... //getters and setters 
}
```

Consider:

- whether existing Trade can be extended to an ExtendedTrade (abstract).
- whether an ExtendedTrade2 might come in existence, with *other* attributes.
- whether you need to patch existing attributes of Trade.

I certainly won't insist that this is better.

Comment: This seems fine to me thought the `new String()` is a bit strange

Comment: @MikeTung corrected (was in the original question), saving 3 constructor calls for a constant in the constant pool of the class.

Comment: It might better honestly if in the constructor we just default the values?

Comment: @MikeTung _indeed:_ **field initialisation** does not happen with serialization, hence transient fields would be nulled anyway. Also the field initialisation code is duplicated in every constructor, which for ~50 fields would bloat the classes somewhat.